# Post to facebook feed allowed without any rules?

Tags: facebook, feed, rules

When a player completes a mission, I will automatically post on his feed something like this:

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/42343242343/feed";

'name'          => "Title3",
'link'          => "www.google.com",
'description'   => 'description here',
```

Technically, it's all working now, but the rules/policy of Facebook is not really clear to me. Do I have to ask the player permission every time? (not the technical permission, because they already give it the first time they login)

I just want to post there automatically when a player does some action. It's a game that is not ON Facebook, but using Facebook login.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Facebook Policy (http://developers.facebook.com/policy/) isn’t really clear here, as it states:

> If a user grants you a publishing permission, actions you take on the
>   user's behalf must be expected by the user and consistent with the
>   user's actions within your app.

But unfortunately, most likely you have to ask the player permission every time.
See explanation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/policy_checklist/english/:

> App does not automatically post Stream stories on a user’s behalf and
>   instead obtains consent by providing users with an option to click a
>   button or check a box that clearly explains their content will be
>   shared.

This is certainly not about permission given at the first login.